# SVG <use> with xlink:href is not working in Edge

Tags: html, svg, microsoft-edge

I'm experiencing weird behavior in Edge that it doesn't call the `<paths>` defined in the **same document**. Though this only happens in my app but not on the style guide. Also, I wasn't thinking that this is a Edge problem since based [from microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/graphics/svg#xlinkhref) they are supporting `xlink:href` attribute.

**Style Guide** (viewed in Edge)
[image]
*From here you can see that the svg icon is rendering just fine, though from the console(DOM Explorer) the `<use>` element is being used and referenced to each path by ID not external svg resources.* Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kfL7tbcf/

**Web App** (missing svg)
[image]
*In the web app, when I tried to use the SVG, it is not getting the referenced  by  element.* Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kfL7tbcf/

**Web App** (svg without `<use>` element)
[image]
*SVG displays okay without `<use>` element.* Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9uuLr9gd/

Any thoughts and help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please post code, not images of code. I.e. we need a [mcve] here.

Comment: @RobertLongson Sorry about that, I just thought it would much makes sense if I added the image code pointed where specific element, nevertheless I've added a fiddle for each. Thanks btw

Comment: Your first and second fiddles are same. And this is displayed fine in  Edge

Comment: @Alexander yeah, I was able to replicate that too, it seems to display fine in Edge, but when it's rendered in our webapp, it doesn't like it. do you think it would be a server problem?

Comment: In first, try to add *xlink* namespace definition (see my answer). If the solution does not help you, show actual code snippet, please (not image!)

Comment: One quetion. Do you use [inline SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction)?

Comment: no I didn't use inline SVG

Comment: oh.. This is a known issue when using `<img>` or `background-image`. Use inline SVG if it is possible!

Comment: Sorry my bad, I read it wrong. I'm using inline SVG. I'm guessing the <use> element isn't working when viewed in our web app in Edge. Please see screen capture no. 2 above. Thanks for your answers Alexander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use inline SVG to avoid the [problem](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-5)!** Run the snippet in the Edge and you will be see the question mark. For reliability, you could add `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` namespace definition to the `svg` element.

```html
<svg id="action-help" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" >
<defs>
  <path id="qMark" d="M10 19h3v3h-3v-3m2-17c5.35.22 7.68 5.62 4.5 9.67-.83 1-2.17 1.66-2.83 2.5C13 15 13 16 13 17h-3c0-1.67 0-3.08.67-4.08.66-1 2-1.59 2.83-2.25C15.92 8.43 15.32 5.26 12 5a3 3 0 0 0-3 3H6a6 6 0 0 1 6-6z"></path>
</defs>
<use xlink:href="#qMark"/>
</svg>
```

For your case:

```html
<svg id="dashboard-calculated-lp" viewBox="0 0 1093.82 512" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false">
  <defs>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_b" d="M188 0H0v88h188V0z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_c" d="M32 64c17.673 0 32-14.327 32-32C64 14.327 49.673 0 32 0 14.327 0 0 14.327 0 32c0 17.673 14.327 32 32 32z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_d" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8.012 11.223C4.925 11.223 2.4 8.698 2.4 5.61 2.4 2.525 4.925.07 8.01 0c3.088 0 5.613 2.525 5.613 5.611 0 3.087-2.525 5.612-5.612 5.612zm9.336 9.745a2.297 2.297 0 0 0-2.295-2.295H2.296A2.297 2.297 0 0 0 0 20.968v16.67a2.297 2.297 0 0 0 2.296 2.295H5.02V54.87h7.11V39.933h2.921a2.297 2.297 0 0 0 2.296-2.295v-16.67z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_f" d="M8.012 0v-2h-.045l.045 2zm-2.99 39.933h2v-2h-2v2zm0 14.936h-2v2h2v-2zm7.108 0v2h2v-2h-2zm0-14.936v-2h-2v2h2zM.4 5.611c0 4.192 3.42 7.612 7.612 7.612v-4A3.627 3.627 0 0 1 4.4 5.61h-4zm7.567-7.61C3.851-1.909.401 1.38.401 5.61h4C4.4 3.67 5.998 2.045 8.056 2l-.089-4zm7.657 7.61C15.624 1.42 12.204-2 8.012-2v4a3.627 3.627 0 0 1 3.612 3.611h4zm-7.612 7.612c4.192 0 7.612-3.42 7.612-7.612h-4a3.627 3.627 0 0 1-3.612 3.612v4zm7.04 7.45c.163 0 .296.133.296.295h4a4.297 4.297 0 0 0-4.295-4.295v4zm-12.756 0h12.757v-4H2.296v4zM2 20.968c0-.162.133-.295.296-.295v-4A4.297 4.297 0 0 0-2 20.968h4zm0 16.67v-16.67h-4v16.67h4zm.296.295A.297.297 0 0 1 2 37.638h-4a4.297 4.297 0 0 0 4.296 4.295v-4zm2.725 0H2.296v4H5.02v-4zm2 16.936V39.933h-4V54.87h4zm5.11-2H5.02v4h7.11v-4zm-2-12.936V54.87h4V39.933h-4zm4.921-2H12.13v4h2.922v-4zm.296-.295a.297.297 0 0 1-.296.295v4a4.297 4.297 0 0 0 4.296-4.295h-4zm0-16.67v16.67h4v-16.67h-4z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_g" d="M0 0h54.26v48.696H0V0z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_i" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.39 9.352A4.667 4.667 0 0 1 .714 4.677C.714 2.089 2.872-.07 5.39.002a4.667 4.667 0 0 1 4.676 4.675A4.667 4.667 0 0 1 5.39 9.352zm-2.781 6.36h10.043v17.673H8.413v12.969H2.61V33.442H0s1.235-.665 1.707-1.254c.398-.498.902-2.007.902-2.007V15.713z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_j" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12.152 15.586H3.74v1.923h8.48c.84 0 1.541.712 1.541 1.567v14.538c0 .853-.7 1.565-1.54 1.565H9.56v12.828h1.891V37.106h.7c1.893 0 3.437-1.566 3.437-3.492V19.08c0-1.928-1.54-3.494-3.436-3.494zM1.249 36.876h.767v11.131h1.725V34.914H1.247v1.962h.002zM0 6.546A6.53 6.53 0 0 1 6.547 0a6.53 6.53 0 0 1 6.547 6.546 6.529 6.529 0 0 1-6.547 6.547A6.524 6.524 0 0 1 0 6.546zm1.87.001a4.666 4.666 0 0 0 4.677 4.675 4.667 4.667 0 0 0 4.676-4.675 4.668 4.668 0 0 0-4.676-4.675C4.029 1.8 1.87 3.959 1.87 6.547z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_k" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.215 9.352a4.668 4.668 0 0 1-4.677-4.676A4.668 4.668 0 0 1 7.215 0a4.668 4.668 0 0 1 4.676 4.676 4.667 4.667 0 0 1-4.676 4.676zm2.828 6.36H0v17.673h4.174v12.968h5.804V33.442h2.61s-1.236-.665-1.708-1.254c-.312-.39-.688-1.4-.837-1.82V15.712z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_l" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M11.85 48.007h1.724V36.876h.767v-1.962h-2.494v13.093h.003zM1.822 33.614V19.078c0-.853.701-1.566 1.54-1.566h8.485v-1.926h-8.41C1.544 15.586 0 17.152 0 19.078v14.536c0 1.92 1.54 3.49 3.437 3.49h.7v10.903H6.03V35.183H3.437c-.914-.004-1.615-.717-1.615-1.57zm.672-27.068A6.53 6.53 0 0 1 9.04 0a6.53 6.53 0 0 1 6.546 6.546 6.529 6.529 0 0 1-6.546 6.547 6.525 6.525 0 0 1-6.547-6.547zm1.87 0a4.667 4.667 0 0 0 4.677 4.676 4.667 4.667 0 0 0 4.676-4.676A4.668 4.668 0 0 0 9.04 1.87a4.668 4.668 0 0 0-4.676 4.676z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_m" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.716 0C1.722 0 0 1.549 0 3.542v30.06c0 1.992 1.722 3.56 3.716 3.56H20.4c-.06 1.427-.222 2.694-.58 3.697-.436 1.219-1.058 2.006-2.149 2.497h-2.186a1.24 1.24 0 0 0 0 2.477H39.02a1.24 1.24 0 0 0 0-2.477h-2.187c-1.09-.49-1.713-1.278-2.148-2.497-.359-1.003-.52-2.27-.58-3.697h16.683c1.994 0 3.716-1.568 3.716-3.56V3.541C54.504 1.55 52.782 0 50.788 0H3.716z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_o" d="M20.4 37.162l1.998.084.089-2.084H20.4v2zm-.58 3.697l1.883.673-1.883-.673zm-2.149 2.497v2h.429l.391-.176-.82-1.824zm19.162 0l-.82 1.824.392.176h.428v-2zm-2.148-2.497l-1.884.673 1.883-.673zm-.58-3.697v-2h-2.087l.088 2.084 1.998-.084zM3.715-2C.744-2-2 .321-2 3.542h4C2 2.776 2.7 2 3.716 2v-4zM-2 3.542v30.06h4V3.541h-4zm0 30.06c0 3.206 2.73 5.56 5.716 5.56v-4C2.714 35.162 2 34.38 2 33.602h-4zm5.716 5.56H20.4v-4H3.716v4zm14.686-2.085c-.055 1.343-.169 2.314-.466 3.11l3.767 1.345c.42-1.21.63-2.775.695-4.285l-3.996-.17zm-.466 3.11c-.298.834-.603 1.128-1.085 1.345l1.64 3.648c1.7-.764 2.64-2.045 3.212-3.648l-3.767-1.346zm-.265 1.169h-2.186v4h2.186v-4zm-2.186 0a3.24 3.24 0 0 0-3.24 3.239h4a.76.76 0 0 1-.76.76v-4zm-3.24 3.239a3.24 3.24 0 0 0 3.24 3.238v-4c.42 0 .76.34.76.762h-4zm3.24 3.238H39.02v-4H15.484v4zm23.535 0a3.24 3.24 0 0 0 3.239-3.238h-4a.76.76 0 0 1 .76-.762v4zm3.239-3.238a3.24 3.24 0 0 0-3.24-3.24v4a.76.76 0 0 1-.76-.76h4zm-3.24-3.24h-2.186v4h2.187v-4zm-1.365.177c-.483-.217-.788-.51-1.086-1.346L32.8 41.532c.573 1.603 1.513 2.884 3.212 3.648l1.64-3.648zm-1.086-1.345c-.297-.796-.41-1.767-.465-3.11l-3.997.17c.066 1.51.275 3.074.695 4.285l3.767-1.345zm-2.464-1.025h16.684v-4H34.104v4zm16.684 0c2.986 0 5.716-2.354 5.716-5.56h-4c0 .779-.714 1.56-1.716 1.56v4zm5.716-5.56V3.541h-4v30.06h4zm0-30.06C56.504.322 53.76-2 50.788-2v4c1.016 0 1.716.776 1.716 1.542h4zM50.788-2H3.716v4h47.072v-4z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_p" d="M54.212 0H0v2.259h54.212V0z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_q" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1.391 9.74h.005V2.236c0-.453.43-.85 1.096-.85h5.057a.694.694 0 0 0 .8-.688.695.695 0 0 0-.679-.696V0H1.097C.433 0 .001.398.001.85v8.845L0 9.742c0 .387.312.696.696.696a.694.694 0 0 0 .695-.696v-.003z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_r" d="M50.087 0H0v2.087h50.087V0z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_s" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 2.092C0 .936.93 0 2.088 0h32.694c1.153 0 2.088.934 2.088 2.092v23.642c0 1.156-.93 2.092-2.088 2.092H2.088A2.088 2.088 0 0 1 0 25.734V2.092z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_u" d="M2 2.092C2 2.034 2.041 2 2.088 2v-4A4.087 4.087 0 0 0-2 2.092h4zM2.088 2h32.694v-4H2.088v4zm32.694 0c.046 0 .088.036.088.092h4A4.088 4.088 0 0 0 34.782-2v4zm.088.092v23.642h4V2.092h-4zm0 23.642c0 .058-.042.092-.088.092v4a4.087 4.087 0 0 0 4.088-4.092h-4zm-.088.092H2.088v4h32.694v-4zm-32.694 0A.088.088 0 0 1 2 25.734h-4a4.088 4.088 0 0 0 4.088 4.092v-4zM2 25.734V2.092h-4v23.642h4z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_v" d="M32.696 0H0v2.087h32.696V0z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_w" d="M16.696 0H0v1.391h16.696V0z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_x" d="M13.913 0H0v1.391h13.913V0z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_y" d="M15.304 0H0v1.391h15.304V0z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_z" d="M1.391 0H0v20.174h1.391V0z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_A" d="M44 86.128c24.3 0 44-19.28 44-43.064S68.3 0 44 0 0 19.28 0 43.064c0 23.783 19.7 43.064 44 43.064z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_C" d="M85 43.064c0 22.066-18.295 40.064-41 40.064v6c25.896 0 47-20.563 47-46.064h-6zM44 83.128c-22.705 0-41-17.998-41-40.064h-6c0 25.5 21.104 46.064 47 46.064v-6zM3 43.064C3 20.998 21.295 3 44 3v-6C18.104-3-3 17.563-3 43.064h6zM44 3c22.705 0 41 17.998 41 40.064h6C91 17.563 69.896-3 44-3v6z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_D" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.737 0h45.915v63.66H6.437C2.882 63.66 0 59.507 0 54.369V5.579C0 2.5 2.562 0 5.737 0z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_F" d="M51.652 0h2.5v-2.5h-2.5V0zm0 63.66v2.5h2.5v-2.5h-2.5zM5.737 2.5h45.915v-5H5.737v5zM49.152 0v63.66h5V0h-5zm2.5 61.16H6.437v5h45.215v-5zm-45.215 0c-.728 0-1.65-.422-2.497-1.643-.84-1.212-1.44-3.023-1.44-5.148h-5c0 3.013.84 5.847 2.33 7.996 1.484 2.14 3.78 3.795 6.607 3.795v-5zM2.5 54.369V5.579h-5v48.79h5zm0-48.79C2.5 3.943 3.878 2.5 5.737 2.5v-5C1.245-2.5-2.5 1.054-2.5 5.58h5z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_G" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.953 0l.002 1.399a59.864 59.864 0 0 1-.034 1.642 51.256 51.256 0 0 1-.241 3.552c-.189 1.781-.47 3.166-.813 3.914-.276.602-.682 1.444-1.205 1.72a3.418 3.418 0 0 1-1.602.39L0 14.979l45.359-.03c5.19 0 9.088-3.144 9.088-7.922l.06-5.615L54.521 0H3.953z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_I" d="M3.953 0v-2.5H1.449L1.453.003 3.953 0zm.002 1.399h2.5v-.003l-2.5.003zm-.005.458l-2.5-.044v.01l2.5.034zM3.92 3.04l2.499.089v-.005L3.92 3.04zm-.24 3.552L1.194 6.33v.001l2.486.263zm-.813 3.914L5.14 11.55l.001-.002-2.273-1.041zm-1.205 1.72L.498 10.013l1.164 2.212zm-1.602.39l.068-2.5-2.503-.067-.064 2.503 2.5.064zM0 14.979l-2.5-.064-.065 2.565 2.567-.001-.002-2.5zm45.359-.03v-2.5h-.002l.002 2.5zm9.088-7.922L51.947 7v.027h2.5zm.06-5.615l-2.5-.027 2.5.027zM54.521 0l2.5.027.027-2.527h-2.527V0zM1.452.003l.003 1.4 5-.007-.002-1.4-5 .007zM1.456 1.4c0 .079-.001.21-.005.414l5 .088.005-.502h-5zm-.005.424c-.004.342-.014.715-.028 1.135l4.997.167c.014-.438.026-.86.03-1.235L1.45 1.823zm-.028 1.13a47.669 47.669 0 0 1-.228 3.376l4.972.529c.125-1.178.208-2.478.253-3.728l-4.997-.177zM1.194 6.33c-.187 1.769-.442 2.792-.6 3.135L5.14 11.55c.528-1.152.836-2.9 1.026-4.693L1.194 6.33zM.596 9.463c-.138.3-.25.528-.355.696-.05.079-.07.098-.056.083.009-.01.109-.12.313-.228l2.329 4.425c.868-.457 1.39-1.212 1.647-1.62.277-.449.521-.955.665-1.269L.596 9.463zm-.099.552a.964.964 0 0 1-.235.083c-.093.02-.146.02-.134.02l-.135 4.998a5.91 5.91 0 0 0 2.835-.678l-2.33-4.424zm-2.936 2.538l-.06 2.362 4.998.128.06-2.362-4.998-.128zm2.44 4.926l45.36-.03-.004-5-45.359.03.004 5zm45.358-.03c3.087 0 5.964-.937 8.112-2.766 2.18-1.858 3.476-4.534 3.476-7.656h-5c0 1.656-.653 2.941-1.72 3.85-1.098.936-2.766 1.572-4.868 1.572v5zM56.947 7.053l.06-5.615-5-.052L51.947 7l5 .053zm.06-5.614l.015-1.412-5-.054-.015 1.412 5 .054zM54.521-2.5H53.07v5h1.45v-5zm-1.451 0H5.39v5h47.68v-5zm-47.68 0H3.952v5H5.39v-5z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_J" d="M20.924 0H0v1.872h20.924V0z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_K" d="M26.783 0H0v1.872h26.783V0z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_L" d="M21.76 0H0v1.872h21.76V0z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_M" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18.84 31.83l-6.543 4.488-2.065-7.554-7.96-.679L5.652 21 0 15.472l7.243-3.302-.7-7.79 7.717 2.027L18.84 0l4.58 6.407 7.717-2.027-.7 7.79 7.242 3.302L32.027 21l3.38 7.086-7.96.679-2.065 7.554-6.542-4.488z"></path>
    <path id="dashboard-calculated-lp_N" d="M18.84 31.83l.848-1.237-.848-.582-.849.582.849 1.237zm-6.543 4.488l-1.447.395.556 2.035 1.74-1.193-.849-1.237zm-2.065-7.554l1.447-.396-.276-1.01-1.044-.089-.127 1.495zm-7.96-.679L.918 27.44l-.933 1.957 2.16.184.127-1.495zM5.652 21l1.354.646.462-.968-.767-.75-1.049 1.072zM0 15.472l-.622-1.365-1.991.908 1.564 1.53L0 15.471zm7.243-3.302l.622 1.365.967-.44-.095-1.06-1.494.135zm-.7-7.79l.38-1.45-2.066-.543.192 2.128 1.494-.135zm7.717 2.027l-.381 1.45 1 .264.601-.842-1.22-.872zM18.84 0l1.22-.872-1.22-1.707-1.22 1.707L18.84 0zm4.58 6.407l-1.22.872.6.842 1-.263-.38-1.45zm7.717-2.027l1.494.135.19-2.128-2.065.543.38 1.45zm-.7 7.79l-1.495-.134-.095 1.058.967.441.622-1.365zm7.242 3.302l1.049 1.072 1.564-1.53-1.99-.907-.623 1.365zM32.027 21l-1.049-1.072-.767.75.462.968L32.027 21zm3.38 7.086l.128 1.495 2.16-.184-.934-1.957-1.353.646zm-7.96.679l-.127-1.495-1.043.09-.277 1.01 1.447.395zm-2.065 7.554l-.848 1.237 1.739 1.193.556-2.035-1.447-.395zm-7.39-5.725l-6.544 4.488 1.697 2.474 6.543-4.488-1.697-2.474zm-4.248 5.33l-2.065-7.555-2.894.791 2.065 7.554 2.894-.79zm-3.385-8.654l-7.96-.678-.255 2.989 7.96.678.255-2.989zm-6.733 1.462l3.38-7.086-2.708-1.292-3.38 7.086 2.708 1.292zM6.7 19.927L1.049 14.4l-2.098 2.144 5.652 5.528 2.098-2.145zm-6.079-3.09l7.243-3.302-1.244-2.73-7.243 3.302 1.244 2.73zm8.115-4.801l-.7-7.79-2.988.269.7 7.79 2.988-.27zM6.162 5.83l7.717 2.027.762-2.902L6.924 2.93 6.162 5.83zM15.48 7.28L20.06.872 17.62-.872l-4.58 6.407 2.44 1.744zM17.62.872L22.2 7.28l2.44-1.744-4.58-6.407L17.62.872zm6.18 6.986l7.718-2.027-.762-2.901-7.718 2.026.762 2.902zm5.843-3.612l-.7 7.79 2.987.269.7-7.79-2.987-.269zm.171 9.29l7.243 3.301 1.244-2.73-7.242-3.302-1.245 2.73zm6.817.864l-5.652 5.527 2.097 2.145 5.652-5.527-2.097-2.145zm-5.958 7.245l3.38 7.086 2.708-1.292-3.38-7.086-2.708 1.292zm4.607 4.945l-7.96.68.255 2.988 7.96-.678-.255-2.99zM26 28.368l-2.065 7.554 2.894.791 2.065-7.554-2.893-.79zm.23 6.713l-6.542-4.488-1.697 2.474 6.543 4.488 1.697-2.474z"></path>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(-69.818 2909.09) scale(5.81818)">
    <mask id="dashboard-calculated-lp_a">
      <path d="M12-500h188v88H12v-88z" fill="#FFF"></path>
    </mask>
    <g style="mix-blend-mode:normal" mask="url(#dashboard-calculated-lp_a)">
      <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_b" transform="translate(12 -500)" fill="#FFF" style="mix-blend-mode:normal" opacity=".01"></use>
      <g style="mix-blend-mode:normal">
        <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_c" transform="translate(12 -488)" fill="#E6EAEB" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
        <g style="mix-blend-mode:normal">
          <g style="mix-blend-mode:normal">
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_d" transform="translate(35.479 -477.252)" fill="#FFF" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
            <mask id="dashboard-calculated-lp_e">
              <path fill="#fff" transform="translate(35.479 -477.252)" d="M-2-2h22v59H-2z"></path>
              <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_d" transform="translate(35.479 -477.252)"></use>
            </mask>
            <g mask="url(#dashboard-calculated-lp_e)">
              <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_f" transform="translate(35.479 -477.252)" fill="#A4A9A4" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
            </g>
          </g>
          <mask id="dashboard-calculated-lp_h">
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_g" transform="translate(16.87 -473.391)" fill="#C4C4C4" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
          </mask>
          <g style="mix-blend-mode:normal" mask="url(#dashboard-calculated-lp_h)">
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_i" transform="translate(54.696 -467.828)" fill="#F8F8F8" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_j" transform="translate(53.54 -469.655)" fill="#A4AAA4" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_k" transform="translate(20.305 -467.827)" fill="#F8F8F8" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_l" transform="translate(18.479 -469.655)" fill="#A4AAA4" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
      <g style="mix-blend-mode:normal">
        <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_c" transform="translate(134.391 -488)" fill="#E6EAEB" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
        <g style="mix-blend-mode:normal">
          <g style="mix-blend-mode:normal">
            <g style="mix-blend-mode:normal">
              <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_m" transform="translate(133 -479.036)" fill="#FFF" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
              <mask id="dashboard-calculated-lp_n">
                <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_m" fill="#fff" transform="translate(133 -479.036)"></use>
              </mask>
              <g mask="url(#dashboard-calculated-lp_n)">
                <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_o" transform="translate(133 -479.036)" fill="#A4A9A4" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
              </g>
            </g>
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_p" transform="matrix(.69444 0 0 .83333 144.294 -443.765)" fill="#A4A9A4" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_q" transform="translate(143.565 -473.474)" fill="#A4A9A4" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_r" transform="matrix(1.02083 0 0 1 134.67 -451.21)" fill="#A4A9A4" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
          </g>
          <g style="mix-blend-mode:normal">
            <g style="mix-blend-mode:normal">
              <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_s" transform="translate(162.913 -456.775)" fill="#FFF" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
              <mask id="dashboard-calculated-lp_t">
                <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_s" fill="#fff" transform="translate(162.913 -456.775)"></use>
              </mask>
              <g mask="url(#dashboard-calculated-lp_t)">
                <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_u" transform="translate(162.913 -456.775)" fill="#A4A9A4" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
              </g>
            </g>
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_v" transform="matrix(1.02128 0 0 1 164.637 -451.21)" fill="#A4A9A4" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_w" transform="translate(177.522 -445.645)" fill="#A4A9A4" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_x" transform="translate(177.522 -441.471)" fill="#A4A9A4" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_y" transform="translate(177.522 -437.297)" fill="#A4A9A4" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_z" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1.01724 172.652 -451.21)" fill="#A4A9A4" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
      <g style="mix-blend-mode:normal">
        <g style="mix-blend-mode:normal">
          <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_A" transform="translate(62 -500)" fill="#F3EFE7" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
          <mask id="dashboard-calculated-lp_B">
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_A" fill="#fff" transform="translate(62 -500)"></use>
          </mask>
          <g mask="url(#dashboard-calculated-lp_B)">
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_C" transform="translate(62 -500)" fill="#AE9357" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g style="mix-blend-mode:normal">
          <g style="mix-blend-mode:normal">
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_D" transform="translate(86.87 -475.66)" fill="#FFF" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
            <mask id="dashboard-calculated-lp_E">
              <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_D" fill="#fff" transform="translate(86.87 -475.66)"></use>
            </mask>
            <g mask="url(#dashboard-calculated-lp_E)">
              <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_F" transform="translate(86.87 -475.66)" fill="#A4A9A4" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
            </g>
          </g>
          <g style="mix-blend-mode:normal">
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_G" transform="translate(92.609 -426.979)" fill="#FFF" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
            <mask id="dashboard-calculated-lp_H">
              <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_G" fill="#fff" transform="translate(92.609 -426.979)"></use>
            </mask>
            <g mask="url(#dashboard-calculated-lp_H)">
              <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_I" transform="translate(92.609 -426.979)" fill="#A4A9A4" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
            </g>
          </g>
          <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_J" transform="translate(104.394 -445.702)" fill="#677067" style="mix-blend-mode:normal" opacity=".6"></use>
          <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_K" transform="translate(101.883 -440.085)" fill="#677067" style="mix-blend-mode:normal" opacity=".6"></use>
          <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_L" transform="translate(104.394 -434.468)" fill="#677067" style="mix-blend-mode:normal" opacity=".6"></use>
          <g style="mix-blend-mode:normal" transform="translate(73.478 -485.957)">
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_M" fill="#FFF" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
            <use xlink:href="#dashboard-calculated-lp_N" fill="#AE9357" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"></use>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yeah, the question mark svg is working fine but for this icon https://jsfiddle.net/kfL7tbcf/, it doesn't render anything.

Comment: @Vincent, I moved the namespace description to the root element and element `defs` to the top of the document only. In IE and Edge this is working fin.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the browser scaling is not properly. Try to remove `width` or `height` attribute or both from your CSS element. See details [here](https://gist.github.com/larrybotha/7881691).